# Netty 4.1.0, channelRead doesn't appear to be reading

Tags: java, netty, channel

I've been working with Netty recently, I'm using the Java driver (4.1.0), and connecting my client and my server is working correctly.

What my issue is that the channelRead method doesn't appear to be reading packets. I've tried enabling AUTO_READ, but no success. I was wondering if anyone could be of help in pointing me in the right direction?

My ClientHandler class:

```
public class ClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Object object) {
       System.out.println(object.toString());
    }

    @Override
        public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext) {   
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is your pipeline build?

Comment: Yep! Here it is
http://pastebin.com/x34mRbpP

Comment: How is the server side sending data?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sgBWbBRS Here is the method I'm using to send packets of data. It's not throwing an exception.

Comment: Does the future returned from writeAndFlush indicate success?

Comment: It appears to. If it didn't it would throw the exception no?

Comment: Try following the steps here to see if the server has problems sending: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40862161/1542723

Comment: I've read that, and added the debug, and it seems to be sending fine. Any other suggestions now knowing that it's not an issue with sending?